# image does not center (on mobile view) with bootstrap 3.0

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small website using Bootstrap 3.0 RC1 and I am just trying to center a simple image (with responsive rendering)

So everything seems to work on desktop devices, but when I look at my website on a small device like a mobile, the image is resized (thats good) but NOT perfectly centered.....
I am puzzled..

Any idea?

Many thanks in advance,

I use the following code :

```
<body style="display: block;">
<section class="container">
<header>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-offset-3">
<center><img src="img/grey_wash_wall.png"  class="text-center" title="Hello" alt="World"></center>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
<div class="title col-lg-12">
<h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
</div>        
</div>  
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket on your `.container` CSS.

```
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  background:white;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm unable to replicate this behavior on a mobile-sized browser window using the markup you provided. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nB4UR/4/)

Comment: The image is centered properly in the original and [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nB4UR/4/), so without more information I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: thx sara but i do also have a centered image on  my desktop. it is when i use my galaxy note to see the website that i do not obtain a perfectly centered image

Comment: Bootstrap does no user-agent checking -- only CSS media queries -- so resizing your browser window should accurately replicate anything you see on your mobile device. Try viewing your site on a mobile-sized browser window.

Comment: replaced the <center> with a <div> and everything worked fine! thx sara for your help